# in MS EXCEL how to get the min and max on multiple columns by grouping

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, max, min

| city | building | floor | wing | seatno |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blr | egla | 5F | A | 1 |
| blr | egla | 5F | A | 2 |
| blr | egla | 5F | A | 5 |
| blr | egla | 5F | B | 6 |
| blr | egla | 5F | B | 7 |
| blr | egla | 5F | B | 11 |
| blr | egla | 5F | B | 12 |
| blr | egla | 5F | B | 13 |
| blr | egla | 5F |  | 234 |
| blr | egla | 5F |  | 254 |

in Excel, want to get the min and max result as below

| city | building | floor | wing | seatrange_From | seatrange_To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blr | egla | 5F | A | 1 | 2 |
| blr | egla | 5F | A | 5 | 5 |
| blr | egla | 5F | B | 6 | 7 |
| blr | egla | 5F | B | 11 | 13 |
| blr | egla | 5F |  | 234 | 234 |
| blr | egla | 5F |  | 254 | 254 |

how to do it in excel summarise like above

Answer (score 1):

One way with formulae in ms365:

[image]

Formula in `G1`:

```
=LET(a,"|",z,DROP(REDUCE(0,REDUCE(TEXTJOIN(a,,A1:D1,"Seatrange_"&{"From","To"}),BYROW(A2:E11,LAMBDA(b,TEXTJOIN(a,0,b))),LAMBDA(c,d,LET(x,TOCOL(c,3),e,TEXTBEFORE(d,a,-1),f,--TEXTAFTER(d,a,-1),g,TAKE(x,-1),h,TEXTBEFORE(g,a,-2),i,--TEXTAFTER(g,a,-1),IF(IFERROR((e=h)*(f=(i+1)),0),VSTACK(DROP(x,-1),TEXTBEFORE(g,a,-1)&a&f),VSTACK(x,d&a&f))))),LAMBDA(j,k,VSTACK(j,TEXTSPLIT(k,a)))),1),IFERROR(--z,z))
```

This should now look at all 4 column and make a decision whether or not the `VSTACK()` should include a new row or adjust the previous one.